# Align Fbox to the left

Tags: align, fbox

I am trying to set space for my mathematics answer booklet. I want to align the box to the left of the page but when I use `\parts` or `\enumerate` the alignment shifts. I want to use the entire width of the page irrespective of the type of question. Please don't mind the question. I need help with the formatting only.

```
\documentclass[12]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsfonts, booktabs,color, titling,tabularx,enumitem,multirow,array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric}

\usepackage[left=1.6cm, top=1.50cm, bottom=1.85cm, right=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document} 
\textbf{STRAND 1} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \textbf{COMPLEX NUMBERS} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \hfill{\textbf{15 MARKS}}
\begin{itemize}
\item This strand has \textbf{$5$ Questions}
\item Show all working for \textbf{Questions 1-5}
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
\begin{questions}
\question Evaluate $\sqrt{-100}$ \hfill{(1 mark)}\\
\framebox(510,100){}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\question Two complex numbers \textit{u} and \textit{v} are given as 
\begin{center}
$u=3(\cos {90\degree} +i\sin {90\degree})$\\
$v=5(\cos {180\degree} +i\sin {180\degree})$
\end{center}
Find $uv$ \hfill{(2 marks)}
\framebox(510,140){}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\question Express $\cfrac{13}{3+2i}$ in the form $a+bi$ \hfill{($2$ marks)}
\framebox(510,240){}
\question Let $w=\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{8}i$ 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Find $Arg(w)$, the \textbf{Argument} of w \hfill{($1 \frac{1}{2}$ marks)}
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{


        \vspace*{6cm}

        \begin{flushright}
        $\cfrac{7}{3-\sqrt{2}}= \rule{1in}{1pt}$\\
        (2 marks)
        \end{flushright}
    }
}
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Find $|w|$, the \textbf{modulus} of w \hfill{($1$ mark)}
\item Convert $w$ into \textbf{polar} form \hfill{($1$ mark)}
\item Use \textbf{De Movire's Theorem} to evaluate $w^{6}$ in rectangular form\hfill{($2 \frac{1}{2}$ marks)}
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\question Solve the equation $z^{2}=196i$ obtaining \textbf{two} distinct complex roots.
Leave your answers in polar form. \hfill{($4$ marks)}
\end{questions}
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found  in my collection of list examples the following solution. since you not provide a *mwe* (minimal working example) i do not know anything about your document, so adoption of below *mwe* to your needs i left to you:

**edit:**
now, when more information about your document is know, i adopt my original answer to your document. in this i did the following:

- reorganize your document preamble (do you really need all loaded packages?)
- slightly change/improve definition of environment `wide`
- adopt your document body to suggested solution

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt]{exam}
  \usepackage[hmargin=1.6cm,
              vmargin={1.50cm,1.85cm}]{geometry}
  \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, gensymb}
  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \usepackage{titling}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, shapes.geometric, tikzmark}
  \usepackage{changepage}

  \makeatletter
      \newsavebox\widebox
  \newenvironment{wide}
      {\@parboxrestore%
       \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\leftmargin}%
                  \begin{lrbox}{\widebox}%
                  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
       }{~\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
         \vskip 1ex
         \fbox{\usebox\widebox}
         \end{adjustwidth}
         }
  \makeatother

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \section*{STRAND 1}
  \textbf{COMPLEX NUMBERS} \hfill\textbf{15 MARKS}
      \begin{itemize}
  \item This strand has \textbf{$5$ Questions}
  \item Show all working for \textbf{Questions 1-5}
      \end{itemize}

  \begin{questions}
  \question Evaluate $\sqrt{-100}$ \hfill{(1 mark)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}

  \question Two complex numbers \textit{u} and \textit{v} are given as
      \begin{align}
  u   & =3\bigl(\cos(90\degree) +i\sin(90\degree)\bigr) \\
  v   & =5\bigl(180\degree) +i\sin(180\degree)\bigr)
      \end{align}
  Find $u$ and $v$!                                           \hfill{(2 marks)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}

  \question Express $\cfrac{13}{3+2i}$ in the form $a+bi$ \hfill{($2$ marks)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}

  \question Let $w=\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{8}i$
      \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item Find $Arg(w)$, the \textbf{Argument} of $w$           \hfill{($1\frac{1}{2}$ marks)}
      \begin{wide}
  \vspace{48mm}
  \raggedleft
  $\dfrac{7}{3-\sqrt{2}}=\rule[-1em]{1in}{1pt}$
      \end{wide}
  \item Find $|w|$, the \textbf{modulus} of $w$               \hfill{($1$ mark)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}
  \item Convert $w$ into \textbf{polar} form                  \hfill{($1$ mark)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}
  \item Use \textbf{De Movire's Theorem} to evaluate $w^{6}$ in rectangular form                                                 \hfill{($2\frac{1}{2}$ marks)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}
      \end{enumerate}

  \question Solve the equation $z^{2}=196i$ obtaining \textbf{two} distinct complex roots.
  Leave your answers in polar form.                           \hfill{($4$ marks)}
  \begin{wide}
      \vspace{22mm}
  \end{wide}
  \end{questions}

  \end{document}
  ```

which gives (first page):

[image]

is this what you looking for?

Comment: Zarko can you help me with the code I have uploaded above. I need the boxes to align from the left of the page. But when I use \parts it shifts to the right

Comment: @SamBluez, your code is not complete. missing are document class and document preamble. first you need add both to your (now not working) mwe ... than i can help you further.

Comment: updated. Thats all I have. Am very new to Latex. Sorry

Comment: Zarko Thank You so much. I have been able to edit and use parts of the code you sent. It works great. Thank You for your help

Comment: @SamBluez, i edit my answer. in this i consider your mwe ...